# C# method to call SP with input and output parameters

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, parameters

I am writing C# method to call SP with parameters.
It has input parameters ,which + their values I add using `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`
But I also need output parameter...How do I add it after I added all inputs with  `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`

Answer (score 1):

check [SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) return type, it is `SqlParameter` you can set the `Direction` of it as one of [`ParameterDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var parameter = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(.....

parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use ADO.NET? If so, the SqlParameter class has the property "Direction". Set direction to output and after the query has executed you read the value from that parameter.

Something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", cn);
cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter parm=new SqlParameter("@pkid",SqlDbType.Int);
parm.Value=1;
parm.Direction =ParameterDirection.Input ; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm); 
SqlParameter parm2=new SqlParameter("@ProductName",SqlDbType.VarChar); 
parm2.Size=50; 
parm2.Direction=ParameterDirection.Output; // This is important!
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm2); 
cn.Open(); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close(); 

// Print the output value
Console.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["@ProductName"].Value); 
Console.ReadLine();
```